# strategies to get data from diff database from diff tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

Problem

- I have two databases user_works database and pricing database.
- I want to take a join of two tables user_table which is in user_works
  database & rent_table which is in pricing database using user_id

What I Have done till Now

- I 1st call user_works db.
- Take the ids from user_table.
- Then pass the ids to rent_table in pricing db

Example:

```
$user_id = select user_id fron user_table WHERE name=abc
```

passing $user_id to dbObject user_works db and fetching user ids then

```
$rent = select user_id,rent from rent_table WHERE user_id IN ( $user_ids )
```

passing $rent to dbObject of pricing database
I want to do this in a php application

Is there any better way to do this. The pricing database is really heavy?Like using temporary tables etc..

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: What's a "*diff* database"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dblink from the pricing database connection

```
select r.*
from
    dblink(
        'dbname=user_works password=password user=user',
        $$ select user_id from user_table where name = 'abc' $$
    ) as u(user_id int)
    inner join
    rent_table r on r.user_id = u.user_id
```

You need to create the dblink extension as superuser:

```
create extension dblink;
```

Or create a local view from the remote db:

```
create view user_table as
select *
from
    dblink(
        'dbname=user_works password=password user=user',
        $$ select user_id, name from user_table $$
    ) as t(user_id int, name text)
;
```

Now query it as it were local:

```
select * from user_table where name = 'abc';
```

Comment: Can I use something like a temporary table which can be created and then taking a join over it. Is that possible???

Comment: @Abhishek Edited. You could create a temp table the same way but I guess the view would be better.